# Django - Change login redirect based on current App

Tags: django, python-3.x

So, I'm adding on another app to a webapp that I'm building for my company, this one involving bill creation for invoices. Unless one has a specific account with my website, they should not be allowed to access this specific app.

I am using Django's built-in authentication system. My LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI is set to redirect to one of my apps. However, I would like for the login redirect to send the user to the app that they were previously in after login. How might I accomplish this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with "current app"? There is no such concept in django that an app is "currently active". You can protect views but not apps.

Comment: you can store url of the view in a variable on context and then go to login page. after user logged in, you can redirect to the page that it's url store on that variable.

Comment: @MohammadAli So, essentially what I should do, is import the settings into the views.py, and when the view is loaded within the app, change the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URI? Or am I completely off base?

Comment: @trixn Essentially, in order for a user to use a billing app, they must be logged in. However, the login redirect will send them to an app where a quote can be generated, which is not where they want to be. Currently, because of the way I've coded the view, if a user is already logged in, they'll be redirected to the page where the billing information is entered. However, they can't go from the login page back to the page where, if they were logged in, they'd be sent to the bill creation page.